# split a vector by percentile

Tags: r, vector, split

I need to split a sorted unknown length vector in R into "top 10%,..., bottom 10%"
So, for example if I have `vector <- order(c(1:98928))`, I want to split it into 10 different vectors, each one representing approximately 10% of the total length.

Ive tried using `split <- split(vector, 1:10)` but as I dont know the length of the vector, I get this error if its not multiple

> data length is not a multiple of split variable

And even if its multiple and the function works, `split()` does not keep the order of my original vector. This is what split gives:

```
split(c(1:10) , 1:2)
$`1`
[1] 1 3 5 7 9

$`2`
[1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

And this is what I want:

```
$`1`
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$`2`
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Im newbie in R and Ive been trying lots of things without success, does anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Problem statement

Break a sorted vector `x` every 10% into 10 chunks.

Note there are two interpretation for this:

1. **Cutting by vector index**:

   ```
   split(x, floor(10 * seq.int(0, length(x) - 1) / length(x)))
   ```
2. **Cutting by vector values (say, quantiles)**:

   ```
   split(x, cut(x, quantile(x, prob = 0:10 / 10, names = FALSE), include = TRUE))
   ```

In the following, I will make demonstration using data:

```
set.seed(0); x <- sort(round(rnorm(23),1))
```

Particularly, our example data are Normally distributed rather than uniformly distributed, so cutting by index and cutting by value are substantially different.

## Result

**cutting by index**

```
#$`0`
#[1] -1.5 -1.2 -1.1
#
#$`1`
#[1] -0.9 -0.9
#
#$`2`
#[1] -0.8 -0.4
#
#$`3`
#[1] -0.3 -0.3 -0.3
#
#$`4`
#[1] -0.3 -0.2
#
#$`5`
#[1] 0.0 0.1
#
#$`6`
#[1] 0.3 0.4 0.4
#
#$`7`
#[1] 0.4 0.8
#
#$`8`
#[1] 1.3 1.3
#
#$`9`
#[1] 1.3 2.4
```

**cutting by quantile**

```
#$`[-1.5,-1.06]`
#[1] -1.5 -1.2 -1.1
#
#$`(-1.06,-0.86]`
#[1] -0.9 -0.9
#
#$`(-0.86,-0.34]`
#[1] -0.8 -0.4
#
#$`(-0.34,-0.3]`
#[1] -0.3 -0.3 -0.3 -0.3
#
#$`(-0.3,-0.2]`
#[1] -0.2
#
#$`(-0.2,0.14]`
#[1] 0.0 0.1
#
#$`(0.14,0.4]`
#[1] 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.4
#
#$`(0.4,0.64]`
#numeric(0)
#
#$`(0.64,1.3]`
#[1] 0.8 1.3 1.3 1.3
#
#$`(1.3,2.4]`
#[1] 2.4
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have your vector as a column (named `vec`) in a data frame, you can simply do something like this:

```
df$new_vec <- cut(df$vec , breaks = quantile(df$vec, c(0, .1,.., 1)), 
                labels=1:10, include.lowest=TRUE)
```

Comment: I know I shouldn't comment just to say thank you (hence the upvote) but I spent literally hours looking for this solution, and it worked so well. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
x <- 1:98
y <- split(x, ((seq(length(x))-1)*10)%/%length(x)+1)
```

Explanation:

```
seq(length(x)) = 1..98

seq(length(x))-1 = 0..97

(seq(length(x))-1)*10 = (0, 10, ..., 970)

# each number about 10% of values, totally 98
((seq(length(x))-1)*10)%/%length(x) = (0, ..., 0, 1, ..., 1, ..., 9, ..., 9) 

# each number about 10% of values, totally 98
seq(length(x))-1)*10)%/%length(x)+1 = (1, ..., 1, 2, ..., 2, ..., 10, ..., 10)  

# splits first ~10% of numbers to 1, next ~10% of numbers to 2 etc.
split(x, ((seq(length(x))-1)*10)%/%length(x)+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the vector is sorted, then you could just create a group variable with the same length of vector and split on it. In real case, it will require a little more effort since the length of the vector may not be a multiple of 10 but for your toy example, you can do:

```
n = 2
split(x, rep(1:n, each = length(x)/n))
# $`1`
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5

# $`2`
# [1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

A real case example, where the vector's length is not a multiple of the number of groups:

```
vec = 1:13
n = 3
split(vec, sort(seq_along(vec)%%n))
# $`0`
# [1] 1 2 3 4

# $`1`
# [1] 5 6 7 8 9

# $`2`
# [1] 10 11 12 13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sum() function to determine the positions to extract a section of the vector. Using a logical operator greater than (>) or less than (<) the percentile value you are indicating. Since sum() assigns the value of 1 if TRUE and 0 if FALSE. It is important to order the elements of the vector first.

```
# A vector with numbers from 1 to 100
data <- seq(1,100)

# 25th percentile value and 75th percentile value
ps1 <- quantile(data,probs=c(0.25))
ps2 <- quantile(data,probs=c(0.75))

# Positions to split
position1 <- sum(data<=ps1)
position2 <- sum(data<=ps2)

# Split with positions in a sorted data
sort(data)[position1:position2]
```

The result is

```
25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75
```

In the same way you can divide an ordered vector into 10 equal parts in the following way, specifying the percentiles

```
# A vector with numbers from 1 to 100
data <- seq(1,100)

# sub vectors based on percentiles
subvectors <- quantile(data,probs=c(0.10,0.20,0.30,0.40,0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80,0.90,1))

for (i in 1:length(subvectors)-1){
  
  # Percentiles values
  ps1 <- subvectors[i]
  ps2 <- subvectors[i+1]
  
  # Positions to split
  position1 <- sum(data<=ps1)
  position2 <- sum(data<=ps2)
  
  # Split with positions in a sorted data
  print(sort(data)[position1:position2])
}
```