# Calculate the mean of groups of an unordered vector in R

Tags: r, vector, mean

My question may be very simple!

I have an **unordered** variable.
I would like to cut this variable in *k* groups of equal size and then calculate the mean of each of these groups of values.

```
vec = c(1:10,1:5,2:6)
mean(vec[1:4])
mean(vec[5:8])
mean(vec[9:12])
mean(vec[13:16])
mean(vec[17:20])
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What are the implications of vector being unordered? Are the means you specify what you're after?

Comment: Theses unordered values (let's say X) are associated with other ordered values (let's say Y). I need to compare the quantiles of X to those of (the unordered but associated) Y.

Comment: So, no quantiles then...

Comment: The question was modified folliwng your comment. No quantiles now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split into 5:

```
lapply(split(vec, sort(vec%%5)), mean)
$`0`
[1] 2.5

$`1`
[1] 6.5

$`2`
[1] 5.5

$`3`
[1] 3.5

$`4`
[1] 4.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use `aggregate`

```
vec <- c(1:10,1:5,2:6)

mystep <- 4

bins <- rep(1:ceiling(length(vec)/mystep), each = mystep)
bins <- bins[1:length(vec)]  # removes any "overflow" values due to ceiling
xy <- data.frame(vec, bins)

aggregate(vec ~ bins, data = xy, FUN = mean)

  bins vec
1    1 2.5
2    2 6.5
3    3 5.5
4    4 3.5
5    5 4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vec = c(1:10,1:5,2:6)

# get quartiles, quantiles, or any prob
q <- quantile(vec, c(0.25,.5,.75, 1) )  

# get the means
lapply(q, function(x){mean(vec[vec<=x])})

    $`25%`
[1] 1.6

$`50%`
[1] 2.636364

$`75%`
[1] 3.5

$`100%`
[1] 4.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am sorry but this is not what I need

Comment: ohh, I see, no quantiles are involved :)

Comment: I've now modified my question removing the word "quantile" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547998/split-a-vector-by-percentile), I found a solution

```
vec = c(1:10,1:5,2:6)
aa= split(vec, floor(5 * seq.int(0, length(vec) - 1) / length(vec)))
lapply(aa, mean)
 # To be compared:
mean(vec[1:4])
mean(vec[5:8])
mean(vec[9:12])
mean(vec[13:16])
mean(vec[17:20])
```